# PHP and AJAX - Append new data to a table, and new edit and delete buttons with the generated id

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, append

First of all, excuse my english and I hope I can explain myself.

What I want to do is this: I click on a button -> form for introducing new data and submit button (an id is generated in the database).

When I submit it (I use a modal), the new data is appended to the table with new appended edit and delete buttons... The problem is that I don't know how to assign the new id to those buttons...

Any hint or help, please?

### EDIT:

I have this before the ajax

```
var display = $('input[name="element_display"]').val(); 
var key = $('input[name="element_key"]').val();
```

to take those values which I insert in the form... I don't know how to do the same with the ID (autoincrement in the database).

In Ajax I have this:

```
'<td>'+ '<span class="btn btn-default edit_element" id=' + key + ' 
value="' + key + '">' + '<a href="'+$("#base_url").attr("valor") 
+"dictio/dictio_element/"+key+'" title="Edit">' +'<i 
class="material-icons">edit</i>' + '</a>' +'</span>' +'</td>'
```

To draw the button, but I need the ID, not the key...

Comment: what have you done before? please place your code here

Comment: Please, add some relevant code, that you've tried so far.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following

```
'<td>'+ '<span class="btn btn-default edit_element" id=' + key + ' 
value="' + key + '">' + '<a id="'.$IdVariable.'" href="'+$("#base_url").attr("valor") 
+"dictio/dictio_element/"+key+'" title="Edit">' +'<i 
class="material-icons">edit</i>' + '</a>' +'</span>' +'</td>'
```

and in Jquery you can get the clicked id by

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id); //alert the button id
});
```